# SQL CE 3.5 Insert into multiple tables

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I am working on SQL CE and I have below tables.

*Device*

- DevID - Primary, bigint , autoincrement
- Name - nvarchar(100)
- Voltage - real
- SettingID - bigint , FK_SettingTable

Another Table :

*Settings*

- SettingID - Primary , bigint
- SettingStr - nvarchar(200)

So first table is device table and another is setting table. Device table and setting table has foreign key relationship.

How can I Insert value SQL CE?
My Insert statement looks like

```
"INSERT INTO DEVICE(Name,Voltage) VALUES('xyz',120)".
```

So I can insert value in device table. But how can i insert value in both tables?

Do I need to change my database design?

Updates :

```
*string connstring = "Data Source=C://Documents//DataBase.sdf";
            SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(connstring);
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cnn.Open();

            Random rm = new Random();
            int id = rm.Next();

            string str = "INSERT INTO Settings (SettingID,Settings) VALUES(" + id + ",'" + textBox3.Text + "')";
            SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand( str, cnn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            str = "INSERT INTO Device (Mfr,Model,SettingID) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "'," + id + ")";
            command.CommandText = str;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();*
```

Above code works, but it doesnt look good.  Random number and adding random number by my self in code. 
Isnt there any other more better idea?

Thanks guys for your suggestions. At least it works for me.

Comment: What value are you trying to insert into the settings table?

Comment: @Jason. SettingStr is comma separated pair of values like service|ON,Current|55,comments|No. Setting ID is primary key for setting table.

Answer (score 2):

Write the Settings record first then write the Device record.

Comment: then how i will maintain FK relationship?

Comment: You can have DELETE CASCADE on foreign keys in CE to automatically delete child records when the parent record is deleted. However, when you are inserting into a table with an FKEY (on any database, not just CE), you always have to insert the parent first and then the child.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you will have only one Setting entry for a device ?

If you have multiple Setting entries for the same device, your db structure wont support you. You should remove the SettingId column from the Device table and Add DeviceID column to the Setting table.

Now you can insert the record to the Device table first and then add record to the Setting table with the value of device id as the recent record id of Device table.

If one SettingId can be associated with one ore more Devices, your schema would support it. But in that case, You need to insert your record in Setting table first then use that setting id value to insert record in Device table.